# Wrap divs after div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to wrap the following divs after the button div with javascript/jquery to hide the rows by clicking of the button. I have multiple buttons and multiple rows after the trigger.

```
<div class="button"> </div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 <div class="row"></div>

<div class="button"> </div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 <div class="row"></div>
 ...
```

I would like to achieve

```
<div class="button"> </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="button"> </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="row"></div>
   <div class="row"></div>
   <div class="row"></div>
   <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
```

Thanks!! I just need to know how to wrapAll it the button thing is easy. (hopefully)

Comment: This doesn't need wrapping - just add an additional class on .button dynamically, and then use the general sibling combinator in a CSS rule that hides the following .row elements based on that. `.button.hide-children ~ .row { display: none; }`

Comment: (The general sibling combinator can help with selecting the elements to wrap in jQuery, too, if you insist on doing it that way.)

Comment: Hi Cbroe - thanks for the css solution but it hides all rows not only the once after the button.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution:

```
    $('.button').each(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('button').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    });
```

Comment: Darn, you're right - wasn't as easy as I thought it was using pure CSS. Was working on sth. similar regarding wrapping (https://jsfiddle.net/u9kqh6ee/) - but ended up with a more convoluted solution than yours ... had missed the existence of `nextUntil` this far, thanks!

Comment: Thanks but 2h on this :(

Comment: Although, since we now both discovered .nextUntil ;-), we could do away with the wrapper again - and simply use `$(this).nextUntil('.button').toggle();` in the button click handler to toggle display of the immediately following rows ... https://jsfiddle.net/u9kqh6ee/1/